# What are alternative terms/words for "cognitive dissonance?"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, idioms, word-usage

I grasp the meaning completely, I'm just looking for alternatives ways to express it.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following possibilities. (Not all of them express exactly the concept you are after, but all of them incorporate aspects of it):

- Self-contradictory attitudes
- Rationalization / rationalizing behaviour
- Behavioural inconsistency
- Self-justification
- Polite fiction
- Self-deception
- Victim blaming
- Confirmation bias
- Prejudice
- Excuse-making
- Living a lie
- Being closeted (e.g. as a homosexual, follower of a different faith (or none), member of a different ethnicity)
- Denial behaviours, e.g. denial of responsibility, self-denial
- Plausible deniability
- Projection

Answer (score 3):

More colloquially, someone might say: "I can't get my head around it"

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the term *ambivalence* or its adjective form *ambivalent.*

[*Ambivalence*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalence) is defined as:

> Simultaneous and contradictory attitudes or feelings (as attraction and repulsion) toward an object, person, or action

And that is pretty much the same definition as [*cognitive dissonance*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cognitive%20dissonance).

> Psychological conflict resulting from incongruous beliefs and attitudes held simultaneously

In fact, there are a number of [online articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=ambivalence+cognitive+dissonance&oq=ambivalence+cognitiv&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.6055j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) — such as [this one](http://www.academia.edu/643181/Thinking_and_caring_about_cognitive_inconsistency_When_and_for_whom_does_attitudinal_ambivalence_feel_uncomfortable) entitled "Thinking and Caring About Cognitive Inconsistency: When and for Whom Does Attitudinal Ambivalence Feel Uncomfortable" — that use the word *ambivalence* when describing cognitive dissonance.

Answer (score 1):

The term **Dunning-Kruger effect** is well known enough to have meaning amongst generally educated people.

From Wikipedia:

> The Dunning–Kruger effect is a cognitive bias which can manifest in
>   one of two ways:
>
> - Unskilled individuals suffer from illusory superiority, mistakenly rating their ability much higher than is accurate. This bias is
>     attributed to a metacognitive inability of the unskilled to recognize
>     their ineptitude.
> - Those persons to whom a skill or set of skills come easily may find themselves with weak self-confidence, as they may falsely assume that
>     others have an equivalent understanding.

Eg.

> She was suffering from Dunning-Kruger effect, her cookies were not the morsels of heaven she believed they were, they were palatable, at best.