# Is there a word for the feeling you get when someone you usually disagree with on an issue, brings up something related to that issue?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes that feeling you get when somebody (of a group typically thought of having more power in society) brings up a group (typically thought of having less power in society: minority groups, women, LGBTQ) and you are hesitant to agree with them **even though they are right** (Like, in this hypothetical scenario they factually are, they're not twisting the facts or anything). It's kind of the same kinda gross feeling you probably got when you read "even though they are right" in a post loosely about racism from a stranger on the internet.

This is the best explanation I can come up with. Is there such a word?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Would **cognitive dissonance** fit your request?

Comment: "I hate to agree with you but you are right."

Comment: The situation is often called a [stopped clock](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Stopped_clock) moment (or broken clock  or sudden outbreak of common sense), based on the fact that even the wrongest clock, i.e. one that has stopped, tells the correct time twice a day. (Obviously it's possible to imagine a clock that never tells the correct time and is impossible to predict, but that was very rare in the days of clockwork mechanisms, and even an entirely random clock is right occasionally.) I've no idea what the sensation of experiencing this is called, but you could try searching for such terms.

Comment: If you search here for (CowperKettle's answer) "cognitive dissonance", there are a lot of questions on similar topics, e.g. [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171059/what-are-alternative-terms-words-for-cognitive-dissonance) which includes a list of similar terms, and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287815/a-word-for-knowing-the-truth-but-not-wanting-to-believe-it) on "knowing the truth but not wanting to believe it".

Comment: English doesn't tend to have words for feelings about such specific circumstances. It's not like German, with words like schadenfreude.

Comment: Can you please tell us what language that thought first came from? I'd love to be shot down and as things stand, I don't believe even the Question, let alone the exposition could ever work in English

Answer (score -3):

[Apprehension](https://www.wordfinderz.com/dictionary/apprehension): This captures the sense of hesitation or unease that might arise when you find yourself agreeing with someone from a perceived higher societal position, particularly when discussing sensitive subjects like race or inequality.

Comment: This isn't at all specific to the situation the asker is describing.